# How to use generic in interface in this case?

Tags: java

I designed some `API`s and they took many params. I wanna checked the params, so I designed a `Interface` called `Validator`.

```
public interface Validator<T> {
    boolean validat();
    default T from(Map<String, String> params) {
        return JSON.parseObject(JSON.toJSONString(params), T);  // can't compile
    };
}
```

The return method is invalid. How can I correct it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`T` is a type, not a `TypeReference` as you need for `JSON.parseObject`.

Comment: Maybe it's not good. I remove the `from`. there's no reason to put it here

Answer (score 0):

Which Library are you using?

I suppose that the second parameter of the method **parseObject** is the "Object class" that must be returned from the method call. If this is the case, you need to pass the class reference to the method.

Try this

```
public interface Validator<T> {
    boolean validat();
    default T from(Map<String, String> params, Class<T> destClass) {
        return JSON.parseObject(JSON.toJSONString(params), destClass);  // this compiles
    };
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Interface should not have any method implementation.

Comment: default methods are allowed starting from Java 8.

Comment: Thanks for correcting JF. I was not aware of this change in Java 8.